# How can I know which theorem to use to prove another one?

Tags: soft-question

In class this year a part of what we do is re learning theorems etc from previous years, but a more rigorous way.

However, when I suggest a way to prove those theorems/properties/..., I often get an answer like 'well it's true that this way would prove it, but what you're suggesting uses another a property that is actually a consequence of what you're trying to prove.'

Is there something out there to know if you can 'legally' use a property to prove another, like a database linking the different theorems, what things they depend on, ... ?

---

I know my question isn't the clearer of all, but it's pretty hard for me to explain that. If you feel like you have a nicer way to state it, feel free to suggest an edit.

Comment: Don't use L'Hopital to *prove* the fact that $\dfrac{\sin x}x\to1$ as $x\to0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked a similar question a while ago, and got some excellent answers:

[How do we know whether certain mathematical theorems are circular?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717107/how-do-we-know-whether-certain-mathematical-theorems-are-circular)